# In Gremlin, how can I group pairs of elements by a property from one of them?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

After some traversal I select the elements I'm interested in through `select()`. How can I group by one of the properties from one specific element.

What I did:

```
g.V() // ... some traversal happens here where I obtain a and b
select('a','b').by(valueMap('Name', 'Description', 'Label'))
```

Right now this gets me all the data I'm interested in, something like:

```
[
  {
    "a": { "Name": "A name" ... },
    "b": { "Name": "other name" ... },
  }
  ...
]
```

But I know that b.Name repeats among different pairs of `a,b`, and so I would like to group all the `a` elements under their common `b` element, I think this should be easy to do, but so far I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to rewrite the whole traversal, but since you kept it as a secret, here's how you would do the post-grouping:

```
g.V()...
  select('a','b').
    by(valueMap('Name', 'Description', 'Label')).
  group().
    by(select('b')).
    by(select('a').fold())
```